# How to define promotions with regular expression for non-latin words?

Tags: regex, unicode, utf-8, google-custom-search

The following regular expression works and matches any search query (max 25 characters) starting with the word "How", as a promotion query in Google Custom Search:

```
How\b.{0,25}\b
```

However, it doesn't work when I use a non-latin UTF-8 word, such as the Arabic "كيف":

```
كيف\b.{0,25}\b
```

Anyone knows a solution?

Comment: "Non-English UTF-8 word" is a variation of made-up confusion that I haven't encountered before. +1 for that.

Comment: Relevant (to someone *answering* the question): http://support.google.com/customsearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1751252

Answer (score 0):

I'm not terribly familiar with Google Custom Search, but it seems that this is a JavaScript regex, right?

If so, then the problem is that `\b` indicates a boundary between a "word" character and a "non-word" character, where a "word" character is an ASCII letter, underscore, or digit (`[A-Za-z_0-9]`).

There's no real general solution; JavaScript simply doesn't know anything about individual characters outside the ASCII range, so it can't tell which ones are letters and which ones are not. But you can write something like this:

```
/^كيف(?:\s.{0,24})?$/
```

to match any query that either is *just* the word `كيف`, or else consists of the word `كيف` followed by a whitespace character and up to 24 more characters. I think that should come pretty close to satisfying your requirement.

Comment: Why do you think it would be a JS regex? Regex is Regex.

Comment: @Bergi: "Regex is Regex" is a common misconception; in fact, different regular-expression libraries have different features, and often differ in the details even of features they have in common. For example, even if we only consider languages that took their syntax almost wholesale from Perl, there's a lot of diversity of support and nonsupport for zero-width lookbehind assertions (the `(?<=...)` and `(?<!...)` notations).

Comment: @Bergi You have over 100 answers under the regex tag, surely you didn't mean to say regex flavors are all the same?

Comment: @NullUserException: Of course there are different regex flavours and they all have some different features they support or don't, and there are differences in what they consider to be a word boundary. Yet I couldn't tell from the regex (at least that simple one the OP provided, and without delimiters) in which engine it would be used.

Comment: @Bergi: Oh, O.K., I understand what you're saying now. When I wrote, "it seems that this is a JavaScript regex", I meant "it seems that the code where you'd be examining the Google Custom Search query is JavaScript code", not "your regex looks like it was written for use in JavaScript".

Comment: @Bergi: I, too, am not very familiar with GCS. Actually, if NullUserException's comment to the original question is on-the-mark, then this probably *isn't* in JavaScript. I really don't know.